Laggy keyboard close animation in compose EditText
I have EditText inside Box, after clicking background i want EditText to lose focus, i implemented it like this:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            AndroidUITestingTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Greeting(
                            name = "Android",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(innerPadding)
                                .align(Alignment.Center)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier.clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                onClick = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                }
            )
        ) {
            TextField(value = name, onValueChange = {})
        }
    }
}

But i noticed strange behaviour, if i click on backround fast right after clicking EditText, then when keyboard is closing it changes to keyboard with letters and numbers on top of them, but default keyboar doesn't have them, so it does look laggy
here is how it looks
I noticed that this works not on every device, on my samsung s22 with android 14 its work normal, in video i use adb PixelXl API 31
